# Java Selenium - disable "Save as" download pop up window works only in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code that downloads file successfully to desired location only in headless mode. In normal mode the pop up stil shows up and test fails.

Could you tell me what should be added to the code to disable "Save as" pop up in normal mode, not headless ?

The following code works only in headless mode.

```
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", LocationUtil.getDownloadFolderPath());
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use Robot class
sometimes you need to put some wait time before the new robot object.

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```